# Return from sort block gives "Use of uninitialized value in sort" warning, but only with explicit return

Tags: perl

I'm getting a strange behavior from Perl when I try to `return` from my `sort()` block:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my @data = sort {
    return &special_sort;
} qw/ 6 1 2 /;

use Data::Dumper;
print STDERR Data::Dumper->Dump([\@data]);

sub special_sort {
    # (imagine some custom sorting logic here)
    return $a <=> $b;
}
```

This gives the following messages:

```
Use of uninitialized value in sort at ./mcve.pl line 6.
Use of uninitialized value in sort at ./mcve.pl line 6.
Use of uninitialized value in sort at ./mcve.pl line 6.
$VAR1 = [
          6,
          1,
          2
        ];
```

As you can see, it also failed to sort the list. The odd thing is, the following sort clauses work without any warnings, and sort the data properly:

```
my @data = sort {
    &special_sort;
} qw/ 6 1 2 /;

my @data = sort {
    my $res = &special_sort;
    return $res;
} qw/ 6 1 2 /;

my @data = sort {
    return $a <=> $b;
} qw/ 6 1 2 /;

my @data = sort {
    eval { return &special_sort; }
} qw/ 6 1 2 /;
```

### Question 0

What's going on here? Why do those four work, but the first example doesn't? It shouldn't be the `return` statement causing undefined behavior, since two of the working ones have that.

### Question 1

If it turns out the world isn't perfect and I *can't* (or *shouldn't*) `return` from a block, is there an elegant way to effectively do that?

**Edit:** It was a bug in Perl. <strike>*(Note: I did some checking, and I'm slowly figuring out this is down to my confusion between how Perl handles BLOCKs vs. SUBs, hence Question 1. The question is still interesting IMO, and confusing behavior on Perl's part.)*</strike>

For clarity, I'm using Perl 5.32.0.

Comment: Interestingly `return @{[&special_sort]}` or `return 0,&special_sort` gives no warnings but does not sort correctly

Comment: I suggest you report this issue at the GitHub [issue tracker](https://github.com/Perl/perl5/issues)

Comment: Re your update: `my @data = sort { my_compare($a, $b) } qw/ 6 1 2 /;`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a [bug](https://github.com/Perl/perl5/issues/18081). A fix has been applied, resolving the issue in upcoming Perl 5.34.

In the meantime, you can replace

```
return &special_sort;
```

with

```
&special_sort;                    # Avoids the issue.
```

or

```
return scalar( &special_sort );   # Force scalar context.
```

or

```
return 0+&special_sort;           # Force scalar context.
```

The problem is that `special_sort` is incorrectly being called in void context, which is avoided or circumvented by the above workarounds.

---

I initially claimed that you can't use `return` in a `sort` block because it's not a sub. I also indicated I was confused by the fact that no error was reported. @Håkon Hægland points out that the documentation for [`return`](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/return.html) indicates it *can* be used in `sort` block. And indeed it can be used in other circumstances. There's a bug, which I've reported and which has now been fixed.

Comment: According to [perldoc return](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/return.html) it can be used to return frome a `sort` block..

Comment: Looks like this have been fixed thanks to your bug report! (I prefer to let you edit that in your answer rather than editing myself: you'll phrase it better than I would :D)

Comment: Updated the answer based on the outcome of the bug request I filed.